# Time series data homogenization using climatol package in R - .dah file missing

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to homogenize rainfall time series data for 12 stations in R (RStudio) using homogen tool in climatol package. I used monthly total series computed using dd2m tool. The homogen command runs well and also generates the results including .rda and .pdf files. But I can't see the .dah (homogenized data with missing data filled) and .esh files being created in working folder as expected. 
Any help on what might have happen, and how can I get this result would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I just figured out that we can export the 'would be' content of .dah file by loading the .rda content to R and then writing to a text file. 
> load('rTest_1950-2000.rda')
> write.csv(dah,"C:/Test/Test-dah.csv")
However, if anyone could suggest why it didn't get generated in the first place would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that we can export the 'would be' content of the `dah` file by loading the `rda` content to R and then writing to a text file, i.e.

```
load('rTest_1950-2000.rda')
write.csv(dah,"C:/Test/Test-dah.csv").
```

Comment: is there a homogenized file without, that just contain corrections? (without missing data filled or estimated)